# is there a way to concat or append a textarea value to an email?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form / quiz where the user can have the results "printed" or "emailed" to themselves. Right now I have everything working as expected. However, I cannot seem to append the "textarea" inputs to the email after the label, the labels show up perfectly but the textarea which should be underneath is blank. is this even possible with Jquery? the closest I came was returning "undefined"

html:

```
 there is four total questions with "textarea" like this one below:
       <!--user input-->
        <div class="ddg__options-container">
          <textarea class="textarea--ddg" placeholder="Type here..." id="question-one"
            name="questionOne"></textarea>
        </div>
        <!--end: user input-->
```

jQuery:

```
  function buildEmailBody() {
   $emailQuestions.empty();

$('.container--question').each(function () {
  var $question = $(this),
    label = '<strong>'.concat(
      $question.find('.ddg__question-row').html().trim(),
      '</strong>'
    ),
    answer = '<strong>'.concat(
      $question.find('textarea.textarea--ddg').val(),
      '</strong>'
    );

  $emailQuestions.append(label);
  $emailQuestions.append(answer);
});
```

}

Comment: Although this isn't the problem, but you can use the + symbol instead of concat, it will look cleaner: `label = '<strong>' + $question.find('.question-row').html().trim() + '</strong>' + $('textarea.textarea--ddg').val()`

Comment: Also, in the provided code you don't provide `optionElementsAsText` anywhere and the provided text area isn't wrapped in `container-question` but your `each` goes through `container-question` elements.

Comment: there is an outter div "container-question"....my mistake....thank you for the input :)

Comment: I threw your code into jsfiddle with some modifications for code that you didn't provide and the only issue that I got was the extra `)` after your concats for label https://jsfiddle.net/8ohs5e02/1/

Comment: If you send as html email will need to replace the text line breaks with html ones

Comment: @imvain2 your fiddle works but only if the textarea has a value in the html. My textareas are blank in the form and the user will enter their "answer" for each question. I need to grab the answer dynamically, I simplified the code I had a bit but am still not getting the values. scratching my head over here...lol

Comment: I've updated @imvain2's fiddle to https://jsfiddle.net/gd8bfos4/  Please have a look if this works for you.

Comment: @casenonsensitive PERFECT! thank you!